# CloudSearch expressions are not being returned using .net toolkit

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, expression, geo, amazon-cloudsearch

When using the AWS .NET SDK to execute a cloudsearch searchrequest, expressions are not being returned in the field collection when specified in the SearchRequest.Return property. When passing the following SearchRequest object to a AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient instance we get all fields save for the distance expression. How do we get access to the expression per hit using the SDK?

```
    new SearchRequest
    {
        QueryParser = QueryParser.Structured,
            FilterQuery = "location:['BOUNDING BOX COORDINATES','HERE']",
            Sort = "distance asc",
            Expr = @"{{""distance"":""haversin(SOME LATITUDE,SOME_LONGITUDE,location.latitude,location.longitude) * .621371""}}",
            Return = "_all_fields,distance",
            Query = "(term field=awesome 1)",
            Start = 0,
            Size = 50
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

"How do we get access to the expression per hit using the SDK?"

The short answer is, you don't. There is a shortcoming with the .net sdk as it doesn't return expression values. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=575746
Hopefully it will be resolved soon, until then we'll have to make the request via http and parse the results ourselves... oh the horror. We'll prob just adapt the json into a decorated Hit object with the additional Expr collection so when its fixed it won't be too big of a headache to switch back.